# What does ContainerType[str, ...] mean in Python?

Tags: python, containers, type-hinting, type-annotation

I realize that Python doesn't actually overload functions, but rather,
hints at multiple acceptable types for method input/output arguments.
By itself, this doesn't allow specification of which input types yield
which return types.  Hence, the use of the `@overload` decorator to
designate multiple acceptable type-hinted prototypes.  This is my
synthesis of reading multiple web pages, so if it's not entirely
correct, thanks for correcting me.

The PySpark package has a `rdd.py` module containing the following
method prototype:

```
@overload
def toDF(
    self: "RDD[RowLike]",
    schema: Optional[Union[List[str], Tuple[str, ...]]] = None,
    sampleRatio: Optional[float] = None,
) -> "DataFrame":
    ...
```

I've tried to find information on how to interpret `Tuple[str, ...]`.

[This](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/id/python-types) page talks about
type hinting for containiner arguments in general, but not what ellipsis
mean following a concrete type inside square brackets that suffix a
container type.

The ellipsis don't like it's in the context of slicing, which is another
use that I've seen mentioned online.

The role of the ellipsis differ from representing a no-op body, such as
with `pass`.

***How do I interpret `Tuple[str, ...]`?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context the ellipsis `...` is used to show that the tuple can have an arbitrary number of elements, including zero. i.e.

`Tuple[str, ...]` means that the schema parameter should be a `Tuple` where each element is of type `str`, and it can contain zero or more elements.

Looking at your example, it is being used to allow for flexibility in the number of column names you can provide in the schema.

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

> To denote a tuple which could be of any length, and in which all
> elements are of the same type T, use tuple[T, ...].

Comment: Thank you, Fraser.  I've marked your answer as the answer, but seeing as it is a duplicate, I suspect that I should delete the question....sorry!

Comment: Actually, I'll let the community decide whether/when to delete the Q&A....